# How to get the file creation date even before it is saved in the file system in Python?

Tags: python, file, metadata

In our application, we upload an audio file and then process it. I however want the file creation date before it is saved to the s3 bucket. While I can read the creation date, but the moment it is upload, the creation date changes to the current date and time. I need the original date for sure. So it means, I need to read the file metadata even before the metadata is changed.

I am using Python code for this purpose. Can someone give some pointers on how to achieve this functionality in Python.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The creation date is generated by the bucket. You shouldn't be able to get the creation date before you upload.

Closest alternative I can think of is to use the metadata tag e.g `x-goog-meta-creation` and store your own creation date

```py
policy_fields['x-goog-meta-creation'] = datetime.now()
policy = storage_client.generate_signed_post_policy_v4(
        bucket,
        blob_name,
        conditions=conditions,
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=expiration),
        fields=policy_fields,
    )
```

Or you will have to read the data after upload to get the actual datetime

Comment: Hi Solly, the original file will be on the users laptop. And I need the creation date before it is uploaded on the S3 bucket.

Comment: It is not possible to get the creation date before it is uploaded on s3. Unless you are talking about the file creation date locally. then use `os.path.getctime('file_path')` for windows or `os.stat(path).st_birthtime` for mac and unix.